# how to select index randomly but not the max(tf.arg_max) in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I can use `tf.arg_max` to select the max index in a matrix,
is there a function in `tensorflow`, to select the index randomly in top n?

```
test = np.array([
[1, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 4], 
 [5, 4, 3], 
 [8, 7, 2]])
argmax0 = tf.arg_max(test, 0)
# argmax0 = [3, 3, 1]
```

I need a function to select a index randomly in top 2 for each array.
for example:
the first colmuns [1, 2, 5, 8], top2 are[5, 8], just select one from [5, 8] randomly.
so the final answer may be [3, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0], [3, 3, 1], [3, 2, 0] or more.

Answer (score 0):

You use .argsort method and then take the top N from that

```
N = 3
a = [1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
top_N_indicies = a.argsort()[-N:][::-1]

# top_N_indicies = [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: how to deal with a 2-dims array?

Comment: you want top-N for each row of a 2-dim array?

Answer (score 0):

Get the topk values:

```
values, _ = tf.math.top_k(test, 2)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[3, 2],
       [4, 3],
       [5, 4],
       [8, 7]])>
```

Shuffle the values in every row:

```
shuffled = tf.map_fn(tf.random.shuffle, values)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])>
```

Select the first row of every shuffled row:

```
tf.gather(shuffled, [0], axis=1)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 1), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[2],
       [4],
       [4],
       [7]])>
```

Copy/pastable code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

test = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [5, 4, 3],
    [8, 7, 2]])

values, _ = tf.math.top_k(test, 2)

shuffled = tf.map_fn(tf.random.shuffle, values)

tf.gather(shuffled, [0], axis=1)
```